# Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having troubles linking the inputs of my form into a defined factory that I have injected into the controller that renders the form. Here is my factory:

```
App.factory('DeviceSelection',function() {
   var states=[{selection:{}},{selection:{}},{selection:{}},{selection:{}}];
   return states;
});
```

And here is an input of my form:

```
            <div class="controls">
              <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_managing_editor" value="Managing editor" ng-model='states[0].selection.hours'>
                Yes 
              </label>
              <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="user[role]" id="user_role_area_editor" value="Area editor", ng-model='states[0].selection.hours'>
                No 
              </label>
            </div>
```

So, when I try to click on that Radio box, I see the following in the JS Console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'selection' of undefined
```

Does that mean that I need to initialize the model before the view is rendered. If so, where?

I am trying to achieve a multi-step form, linking all the inputs in the model, until last step is reached when I am able to send the results to an API. As asked here:

[Store status between forms in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889292/store-status-between-forms-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you have injected in your controller. It would be nice to see that injection, but let me blind guess something that might be happening:

I am assuming you have (something like) this:

```
YourApp.controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'YourFactory', function ($scope,$yourFactory) {
...
```

But, have you set that injection into the `$scope`? Otherwise the view won't have access :)

So, if you don't have it, do this:

```
 $scope.states=$yourFactory;
```

I really believe this is what happened. The controller needs to tell the view where to find that state array through the `$scope`